# Make widget fill whole row

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I'm working on a project that has a built-in file manager, and I want every file (a `Button`) to have its own row, but I can't make the `Button` fill the entire row.

I tried making the `Button` sticky to W+E, but it didn't work

```py
def reloadWindow(self):
   for x in self.widgets:
        x.grid_forget()
    self.widgets = []
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in files:
            if not name == "":
                replacer = self.proDir + "\\assets"
                self.helloBTN = Button(self, text=path.replace(str(replacer), "") + "\\" + name)
                self.helloBTN.grid(row=len(self.widgets), sticky=W+E)
                self.widgets.append(self.helloBTN)
```

The actual result looks like this:

[image]

However, I want the `Button` to fill the entire window (the code is executed from a top-level class).

EDIT:
Here is a link to a full window clip [LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDcGD.png)

EDIT2:
A [LINK](https://textbin.net/0hJWmPjY65) to a stripped down mre version of the code. At line 41 please replace [DIR] with a real directory(With 36 files max).

Comment: The three lower buttons seem to have the same width. What's with the first one? Did you want to highlight that one, or make it unreadable?

Comment: No that is a reload button and some other buttons. @tobias_k

Comment: @tobias_k Here is a link to a full window clip [LINK](https://imgur.com/a/sKCTXuI)

Comment: It **is** filling the entire row, the problem is that the Frame it's in is not filling the entire window. We need to see a [mcve] to help with that, but as a guess you can add `self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` to the top of the function.

Comment: Although I think it would be more pythonic to set the width of the Button and let the window adjust to that, rather than setting the width of the window and making the Button match.

Comment: @Novel Here a [LINK](https://textbin.net/0hJWmPjY65) to a stripped down mre version of the code. At line 41 please replace [DIR] with a real directory(With 36 files max).

Comment: @SebastianSnoer ok, so the code I guessed was correct. Add the column weight and you're set.

Comment: @Novel It works! Thanks for the help. How do I close this / make that a the answer?

Comment: Please don't link to a stripped down version. Instead, [edit] your question to directly include a [mcve].